# Loopback stop login while emailVerified is false

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

i have a custom user model (user extended) and i would like to implement a classic double optin and don't permit login while emailVerified is false, I've tried to write an afterRemote method like this

```
    var app = loopback();
        app.currentUser = false; 


    user.afterRemote('login', function(context, user, next) {

      var UserModel = app.models.User;

      UserModel.findById(user.userId, function (err, usr) {

         if (err) {

           return next(err);
         }

         if ( !usr ) {

           return next(new Error('could not find a valid user'));
         }

         console.log('> USER SEARCH: %j', usr);

         next();
    });
```

but UserModel is undefined.

Is this a wrong method to implement double optin in loopback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `beforeRemote` hook since you want to STOP the login action, using an `afterRemote` hook the login has already occurred. Based on the code you shared, however, I'm not event sure how you're doing this or where you put this code. You appear to be attaching the hook to `user`, but then you get the `User` model off the `app` anyway?

I think you will need to extend the core `User` model in order to do this. So create a **new model** with `User` as its `base`:

```
{
  "name": "MyUser",
  "base": "User",
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Then in the `/common/models/MyUser.js` file you have this:

```
module.exports = function(MyUser) {
  MyUser.beforeRemote('login', function(context, unused, next) {

    MyUser.findOne(
      // assuming they log in with their email address...
      { where: { email: context.req.body.email } },
      function (err, user) {
         if (err || !user) {
           return next(err || (new Error('No user found')));
         }

         if (!user.emailVerified) {
           return next(new Error('You need to verify your email first!'));
         }

         next();
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for suggest, it works with this "method" to read property usr[0].emailVerified . Is there a way to read a property without index array?

Comment: Ah right! Because a `find()` always returns an array of records, even if there is only one. You can switch to using `findOne()`